# React, functional component. Input focus is thrown off when a character is entered

Tags: reactjs

I'm new in react. The problem is this - when I enter data into the input, my focus is reset. I understand that it happens due to `changeHandler`. But I don't understand how to change it. I've seen similar problems, but they are all related to class components. I would like to implement the solution exactly in a functional component, not using classes.

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { AuthContext } from '../context/AuthContext'
import axios from 'axios';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

export const AuthPage = () => {
  const auth = useContext(AuthContext)
  const [typeOfForm, setTypeOfForm] = useState('login')
  const [form, setForm] = useState({
    email: '', password: ''
  })
  const loginHandler = async () => {
    try {
      var config = {
        headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }
      };
      axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/login', { ...form }, { headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${auth.token}` } })
        .then(response => response.data.map(part => { auth.login(part.token, part.userId); console.log(part) }))
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    } catch (e) { }
  }

  const registerHandler = async () => {
    try {
      var config = {
        headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${auth.token}` }
      };
      axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/register', { ...form })
        .then(response => response.data.map(part => { auth.login(part.token, part.userId); console.log(part) }))
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    } catch (e) { }
  }

  const changeHandler = event => {
    setForm({ ...form, [event.target.name]: event.target.value })
  }


  return (
    <div className="App" key="editor2">
      <div className="logreg-bg"></div>
      <a href="/">
        <h1 id="logreg-logo">Animal Assistance <br /> <span id="logreg-logo-down">save nature togehter</span></h1>
      </a>
      {typeOfForm == 'login' ? <LoginForm /> : <RegisterForm />}
      <h1 id="logreg-logo2"> Created by: <br /> <span id="logreg-logo-down2">PTN</span></h1>
    </div>

  );

  function LoginForm() {
    return (
      <div id="logreg-form-container">
        <h1 id="form-header">Log in</h1>
        <div id="label-logreg-input">
          <div className="logreg-labels">
            <label htmlFor="email" id="login-label">Email</label>
          </div>
          <input
            placeholder="Email"
            type="text"
            id="login"
            name="email"
            value={form.email}
            onChange={changeHandler}
            required />
        </div>
        <div id="label-logreg-input">
          <div className="logreg-labels">
            <label htmlFor="password" id="password-label">Password</label>
          </div>
          <input
            placeholder="Password"
            type="password"
            id="password"
            name="password"
            value={form.password}
            onChange={changeHandler}
            required />
          <div id="logreg-button-container">
            <button
              onClick={registerHandler}
              id="logreg-form-button"
            >Login</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="go-to-else-container">
          <a id="go-to-else"
            onClick={() => setTypeOfForm('register')}>Register</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  function RegisterForm() {
    return (
      <div id="logreg-form-container">
        <h1 id="form-header">Register</h1>
        <div id="label-logreg-input">
          <div className="logreg-labels">
            <label htmlFor="email" id="login-label">Email</label>
          </div>
          <input
            placeholder="Введите email"
            value={form.email}
            onChange={changeHandler}
            type="text"
            id="login"
            name="email"
            required />
        </div>
        <div id="label-logreg-input">
          <div className="logreg-labels">
            <label htmlFor="password" id="password-label">Password</label>
          </div>
          <input
            placeholder="Введите пароль"
            value={form.password}
            onChange={changeHandler}
            type="password"
            id="password"
            name="password"
            required />
          <div id="logreg-button-container">
            <button
              type="submit"
              id="logreg-form-button"
            >Register</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="go-to-else-container">
          <a id="go-to-else"
            onClick={() => setTypeOfForm('login')}>Login</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default AuthPage;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems:

1. Focus is being lost because currently, input changes the state of a higher level component. The automatically causes a re-rendering of its child (the login or sign up form), because it is being completely defined again.

- This causes an automatic re-render since React and browser think it
  got a COMPLETELY NEW component.

Solutions:

1. Move the form state, and changeHandler function, to each respective form component, and allow them to manage their state independently. That way, this won't happen.

**Recommended Approach:**

2. If you want to form and changleHandler in a higher level component, then define the child components (Login and Sign Up) separately from AuthPage. Then just pass them the form state, and changeHandler function, as props.

Below if the 2nd approach being implemented

Since you would define both components separately, ensure you pass all the variables and functions in AuthPage, that are needed in each form, as props/parameters too. This is for functional purposes, and because it is best practice for maintenance on react apps.

Let me know if it helps :)

```js
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { AuthContext } from '../context/AuthContext'
import axios from 'axios';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

function LoginForm({form, changeFormType, changeHandler, registerHandler}) {
    return (
      <div id="logreg-form-container">
        <h1 id="form-header">Log in</h1>
        <div id="label-logreg-input">
          <div className="logreg-labels">
            <label htmlFor="email" id="login-label">Email</label>
          </div>
          <input
            placeholder="Email"
            type="text"
            id="login"
            name="email"
            value={form.email}
            onChange={changeHandler}
            required />
        </div>
        <div id="label-logreg-input">
          <div className="logreg-labels">
            <label htmlFor="password" id="password-label">Password</label>
          </div>
          <input
            placeholder="Password"
            type="password"
            id="password"
            name="password"
            value={form.password}
            onChange={changeHandler}
            required />
          <div id="logreg-button-container">
            <button
              onClick={registerHandler}
              id="logreg-form-button"
            >Login</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="go-to-else-container">
          <a id="go-to-else"
            onClick={changeFormType}>Register</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  function RegisterForm({form, changeFormType, changeHandler}) {
    return (
      <div id="logreg-form-container">
        <h1 id="form-header">Register</h1>
        <div id="label-logreg-input">
          <div className="logreg-labels">
            <label htmlFor="email" id="login-label">Email</label>
          </div>
          <input
            placeholder="Введите email"
            value={form.email}
            onChange={changeHandler}
            type="text"
            id="login"
            name="email"
            required />
        </div>
        <div id="label-logreg-input">
          <div className="logreg-labels">
            <label htmlFor="password" id="password-label">Password</label>
          </div>
          <input
            placeholder="Введите пароль"
            value={form.password}
            onChange={changeHandler}
            type="password"
            id="password"
            name="password"
            required />
          <div id="logreg-button-container">
            <button
              type="submit"
              id="logreg-form-button"
            >Register</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="go-to-else-container">
          <a id="go-to-else"
            onClick={changeFormType}>Login</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

const AuthPage = () => {
  const auth = useContext(AuthContext)
  const [typeOfForm, setTypeOfForm] = useState('login')
  const [form, setForm] = useState({
    email: '', password: ''
  })
  const loginHandler = async () => {
    try {
      var config = {
        headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }
      };
      axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/login', { ...form }, { headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${auth.token}` } })
        .then(response => response.data.map(part => { auth.login(part.token, part.userId); console.log(part) }))
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    } catch (e) { }
  }

  const registerHandler = async () => {
    try {
      var config = {
        headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${auth.token}` }
      };
      axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/register', { ...form })
        .then(response => response.data.map(part => { auth.login(part.token, part.userId); console.log(part) }))
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    } catch (e) { }
  }

  const changeHandler = event => {
    setForm({ ...form, [event.target.name]: event.target.value })
  }

  const changeFormType = event =>{
      //add your condition based of e.target
       setTypeOfForm('login')
      //add your condition based of e.target
       setTypeOfForm('register')
  }
  return (
    <div className="App" key="editor2">
      <div className="logreg-bg"></div>
      <a href="/">
        <h1 id="logreg-logo">Animal Assistance <br /> <span id="logreg-logo-down">save nature togehter</span></h1>
      </a>
      {typeOfForm == 'login' ? <LoginForm 
                                    changeHandler={changeHandler} 
                                    form={form} 
                                    changeFormType={changeFormType}
                                    registerHandler={registerHandler}/> 
                                : <RegisterForm 
                                    changeHandler={changeHandler} 
                                    form={form} 
                                    changeFormType={changeFormType}
                                />}
      <h1 id="logreg-logo2"> Created by: <br /> <span id="logreg-logo-down2">PTN</span></h1>
    </div>

  );
}

export default AuthPage;
```

Comment: Yes, that helped, I had already done something like that, but I only had 1 problem, with ` <a id="go-to-else" onClick={() => setTypeOfForm('login')}>Login</a>` Now i have only 1 error, it is "'setTypeOfForm' is not defined" :(

Comment: You can define a function similar to changeHandler, in AuthPage scope, that handles setTypeOfForm. Then pass that function into  RegisterForm and LoginForm as a prop.

Comment: I actually updated the current code in my snippet, with the full fix, and comments where you need to write some conditional logic to change the form types. Let me know how it goes :) !

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, everything works now :)